Usage of きらめき in song lyrics
In the song 'room' by iri, a section goes like this:

色とりどりの夢を
きらめき次第に
溢れていく命を
何一つもたやさずに

I can't figure out what きらめき is doing here, and how to translate the thought as a whole. For more context, surrounding lyrics are here. I'm not sure if it's supposed to connect to the lines preceding or following it, or if it's separate from both.

The two を mark the two parallel objects of 絶やさず, so it's basically parsed like this:

輝く日々と色とりどりの夢を何一つもたやさずに
きらめき次第に溢れていく命を何一つもたやさずに

きらめく is a verb that means "to sparkle/glitter", and きらめき次第に means "as soon as [something] sparkles" (grammar). きらめき次第に溢れていく is a relative clause that modifies 命.
So a literal translation would be something like this:

輝く日々と色とりどりの夢を、きらめき次第に溢れていく命を、何一つもたやさずに
Never letting go of a single one of the shining days and colorful dreams
And (never letting go of a single one of) the lives that overflow as soon as they start to sparkle

(This (きらめき)次第に can also possibly mean "(glittering and) gradually", but based on how this part is actually sung, I think this interpretation is unlikely.)
